# frame tall walls

Tags: walls, framing, construction

I received drawing from an engineer and it has an loft style opening in the front part of the house. This section of the house is to be 17'2'' and is going to be framed with 2x4. My question is how do you frame this part with no joists with it being so tall?

Do you stack walls on top of each other?

Also with the front of the house having tall windows, how do I figure the header size?

Comment: If an engineer is supplying the drawings, is he not also specifying the lumber to be used? If not, maybe you should ask him.

Answer (score 1):

If the wall is rectangular and not trapezoidal,  it is typically built on the floor (trapezoidal is too, but a slightly different process). The header for the window is either sized by the engineer or it will be listed in the code book.

When the wall is finished assembled is is taken to the layout line on the floor where it is to be permanently located and toenail to the line so the nail heads are driven through the upper face of the bottom plate. If you can square and straighten the plates and studs, this is when you can also set the subsiding. If and after that is done, pull all the toenails holing the sides and top plate, leaving the toenails at the bottom, nail short blocks vertically about 5' apart at the out of the foundation.
Begin standing the wall up, the toenails at the bottom will keep the wall from sliding, as the wall goes up, the toenails will release eventually and the blocks that are nailed on the outside face will keep the wall on the layout line.

An extra tip would be to have your bracing in place attached to the sides of the wall high enough so you can be ready to attach them to the floor once the wall is raised.

Answer (score 0):

This wall is illegal for two reasons: 1) exceeds maximum height allowed by code, and 2) too narrow for minimum insulation required by code.

1. The maximum height allowed by code is 10’ without lateral bracing or without structural analysis that accompany the drawings. (See ICC Table R602.3(5) )
2. The Energy Code requires a 2x6 stud in order to provide adequate depth for batt insulation. (You can provide R-11 or R-13 insulation in a 2x4 wall and then add ridged insulation to comply in lieu of 2x6 stud wall. Was this included on the drawings?)

I’d ask the engineer for clarification on these two items before you proceed.

Comment: "*The Energy Code requires a 2x6 stud*" This is only in some areas, no?